# Изменения стора redux не вызывает рендер компонента

Tags: javascript, redux, react-native

Использую [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), cтолкнулся с проблемой:

**sensors.ts:**

```
export const sensorsActions = {
  doGetSensorsListRequest: createAction<string, 'doGetSensorsListRequest'>(
    'doGetSensorsListRequest',
  ),
  doGetSensorsListSuccess: createAction<ISensor[], 'doGetSensorsListSuccess'>(
    'doGetSensorsListSuccess',
  ),
  doGetSensorsListFailure: createAction<string, 'doGetSensorsListFailure'>(
    'doGetSensorsListFailure',
  ) 
}
```

**sensorsThunks.ts**

```
export function doGetSensorsList(svr_id, acc_pu) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(doGetSensorsListRequest());
    return OnlineGateService.getSensorsList(svr_id, acc_pu)
      .then(result => dispatch(doGetSensorsListSuccess(result.data.sensors)))
      .catch(result => {
        dispatch(
          alert({
            title: 'Ошибка',
            text: 'Не удалось получить список счетчиков',
          }),
        );
        return dispatch(doGetSensorsListFailure(result));
      });
  };
}
```

**sensorsReduser.ts**

```
type SensorsState = {
  inProgress: boolean;
  sensorsList: ISensor[];
};

const initialState: SensorsState = {
  inProgress: false,
  sensorsList: [],
};

export default createReducer(initialState, builder => {
  builder.addCase(doGetSensorsListRequest, state => {
    startLoading(state);
  });
  builder.addCase(doGetSensorsListSuccess, (state, action) => {
    state.inProgress = false;
    state.sensorsList = action.payload;
  });
  builder.addCase(doGetSensorsListFailure, (state, action) => {
    loadingFailure(state, action);
  });
}
```

**SensorsList.tsx**

```
class SensorsList extends Component<Props, State> {
  ...

  data = [
    {title: 'Активные счетчики', data: this.props.sensors.active},
    {title: 'Архивные счетчики', data: this.props.sensors.archived},
  ];

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData(this.info.id, this.info.account_id);
  }

  renderRow = rowData => {
   ...
    const sensorInfo = (
      <View style={styles.sensorRow}>
        <RoundLabel
          icon_name={rowData.sensor_type.icon_name}
          color={icon_color}
        />
        <View style={styles.directionColumn}>
          <Text style={styles.textMain}>{rowData.display_name}</Text>
          {rowData.custom_name ? (
            <Text
              style={styles.textThird}
              numberOfLines={1}
              ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
              {rowData.custom_name}
            </Text>
          ) : null}
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
          <Text style={styles.textMain}>{rowData.last_sensor_value}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.textThird}>{rowData.last_sensor_date}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );

    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        ...
        onPress={() => navigation.push('sensorDetail', {})}>
        {sensorInfo}
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (     
    
        <SectionList
          sections={this.data}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({item}) => this.renderRow(item)}
          renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
            <Text style={styles.textSecond}>{title}</Text>
          )}
          refreshing={this.props.inProgress}
          onRefresh={() => this.loadData(this.info.id, this.info.account_id)}
        />
    );
  }

  loadData = (srvId, accPu) => {
    this.props.loadData(srvId, accPu);
  };
}

const dataSelector = createSelector(
  [(state: AppState) => state.sensors.sensorsList],
  state => ({
    active: state.filter(item => item.status_name === 'Активен'),
    archived: state.filter(item => item.status_name === 'Перемещен в архив'),
  }),
);

const connector = connect(
  (state: AppState) => {
    return {
      sensors: dataSelector(state),
      inProgress: state.sensors.inProgress,
    };
  },
  {
    loadData: doGetSensorsList,
  },
);

type ReduxProps = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

export default connector(SensorsList);
```

После того как отработал reducer, стор корректно поменялся, но компонент не перерисовывается и остается пустым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том что SectionList брал данные из свойства data:

```
class SensorsList extends Component<Props, State> {
  ...

  data = [
    {title: 'Активные счетчики', data: this.props.sensors.active},
    {title: 'Архивные счетчики', data: this.props.sensors.archived},
  ];

  ...
}
```

Чтобы всё заработало нормально я

переделал dataSelector:

```
const dataSelector = createSelector(
  [(state: AppState) => state.sensors],
  state => ({
    
      sensors: [
        {
          title: 'Активные счетчики',
          data: state.sensorsList.filter(
            item => item.status_name === 'Активен',
          ),
        },
        {
          title: 'Архивные счетчики',
          data: state.sensorsList.filter(
            item => item.status_name === 'Перемещен в архив',
          ),
        },
      ],
    };
  )
);
```

и переделал SectionList:

```
<SectionList
  sections={this.props.sensors.sensors}
  extraData={this.props.sensors}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
  renderItem={({item}) => this.renderRow(item)}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <Text style={styles.textSecond}>{title}</Text>
  )}
  refreshing={this.props.inProgress}
  onRefresh={() => this.loadData(this.info.id, this.info.account_id)}
/>;
```